# onDraw() method doesnt work right

Tags: android, canvas, view, ondraw

So, iv created class that extends view. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mTablesList.isEmpty()) {
        drawTables(canvas);
    }

}

 private void drawTables(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Table table : mTablesList) {

            canvas.drawRect(mWidht * table.getLeft() / 100, mHeight * table.getTop() / 100, mWidht * table.getRight() / 100, mHeight * table.getBottom() / 100, m1Paint);
            saveInfo(table, mWidht * table.getLeft() / 100, mHeight * table.getTop() / 100, mWidht * table.getRight() / 100, mHeight * table.getBottom() / 100);

    }
}

private void saveInfo(Table table, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);


    table.setRect(rect);
    mTablesListTouch.add(table);
}
```

Now, I have 2 objects that are needed to be drawn. The first object always gets drawn, but the second one doesn't. When my 2nd objects coordinates are left and top == left and top, it doesnt show, when the object is drawn below object 1 that is drawn, it shows. Can somebody give me a solution?

```
private void makeTables() {

    Table table = new Table();

    table.setLeft(20);
    table.setTop(7);
    table.setRight(40);
    table.setBottom(20);
    table.setAvailable(true);
    table.setID(1);
    listOfTables.add(table);

    Table table1 = new Table();

    table1.setLeft(20);
    table1.setTop(70);
    table1.setRight(60);
    table1.setBottom(20);
    table1.setAvailable(true);
    table1.setID(2);
    listOfTables.add(table1);



    mTables.setTables(listOfTables);
}
```

settin mTables.

ok, so, this is setTables() method:

```
 public void setTables(List<Table> tables) {
    mTablesList = tables;
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    invalidate();
}
```

after it it callse onMeasure() and onDraw()

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);


    mWidht = width;
    mHeight = height;

    setMeasuredDimension(mWidht, mHeight);

}
```

Comment: Bring a code where you are filling mTablesList

Comment: it is inside activity, from there im calling setTables() method

Comment: Ok. now, what inside "setTables()"? Better if you bring a full lifecycle of your "tables" from creation.

Comment: done and done. So, it has tables, size is 2, it has everything, it just doesnt draw the second table object.

Comment: Better do not use a width and height given in onMeasure. Because it is used just to estimate future size. You can get actual size of the view from onLayout. Or just in anytime, using getWidth() and getHeight() methods. I think your table is drawn, but below the visible part of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the coordinates right. table.setLeft(20) is the value from left margin to the left side of the object, table.setRight(30) is from left margin to the right side of the object. So, allways table.setRight> table.SetLeft same goes for top and bottom.